# App Store Connect Notary Service Agreements Error

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I'm signing my macOS application with a Developer ID Application Certificate and sending it to Apple's notary service. When I'm uploading the build from XCode I'm getting the following error:

> Failed retrieving request UUID for upload. You may have outstanding
> agreements to sign on App Store Connect.

I've checked the following URLs and I don't have any new prompts for new agreements:

https://developer.apple.com/account/

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/

Is this a bug from Xcode/App Store Connect or does the message refer to other agreements that must be signed?

Answer (score 1):

After failing to solve this with an Apple Support person, I removed an admin who did not have a current individual Apple Development account from the Team.  Solved the issue instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and also no outstanding agreements to sign.
In the end, the problem was, that the user who wanted to upload the build for notarization didn't have "Access to Cloud Managed Developer ID Certificate" in the *Users and Access* section on App Store Connect. It worked before for that user, so something in the backend must have changed in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, no agreements to sign, I had Access to Cloud Managed Developer ID Certificate and still got the error.
To fix it I went to Xcode->Preferences-> removed my developer account from Xcode the re-added my developer account to Xcode and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Update from November 2022: I no longer receive the error from the question, it was probably fixed by Apple on their side.